# Fresh install boots into grub

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, grubrescue, grub-efi

Linux newbie here. Just recently reinstalled Ubuntu and every time I boot, I get thrown into the grub shell. I've looked everywhere, wasted a lot of time and can't track the problem for the life of me.

The partition table is laid out as:
/dev/sda1 - The actual OS
/dev/sda2 - EFI 
/dev/sda3 - Swap

By running:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt1)
linux /vmlinuz_something root=/dev/sda1 ro
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

I boot into the OS and then run update-grub. It appears as it has succesfully located the kernels updated the entries, but still boots into grub. So I further looked into the issue and ran into some instances suggesting it might have something to do with the way GRUB handles booting following unsuccesful boot attempts.

From what I could make out of those, I decided to try and add to my /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
```

I ran update-grub once more and the issue persisted. Also tried other values as a guess, which didn't work unsurprisingly. I apologize for  bringing up this exhausted topic, but the solutions I found just haven't worked for me. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried `root=UUID=xxxxx` instead of `root=/dev/sda1` ?

Comment: Just tried it, but it still boots into Grub.

Comment: take a look at https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Efi_installieren and  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that you've got two GRUB installations -- maybe one for one distribution and another for another; or one BIOS-mode and one EFI-mode. In either case, if you're updating the configuration file for one GRUB but another one executes, you'll see symptoms like what you're seeing.

If you've got two EFI-mode GRUB installations, you should see evidence of them in your `sudo efibootmgr -v` output and/or in files on your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition), which is normally mounted at `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu. Try the following commands:

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
sudo find /boot/efi -iname "*.efi"
```

The first shows boot loaders that are registered with the firmware, including their paths. If you see multiple references to `shim.efi`, `shimx64.efi`, `grub.efi`, or `grubx64.efi` (that is, more than one from this set), that could be the issue. The second command finds all the boot programs on your ESP (assuming it's mounted at `/boot/efi`). Again, multiple boot programs could be an issue -- but in this case, one Shim can coexist with one GRUB; it's just multiple GRUB binaries that could be a problem.

If you've got one BIOS-mode and one EFI-mode GRUB, that may be harder to detect. The easiest way to do so is to run the [Boot Info Script,](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) which identifies both BIOS-mode and EFI-mode boot loaders, but takes some experience to interpret.

You may want to post the `RESULTS.txt` file that Boot Info Script produces, along with output of those two commands I noted, to [a pastebin site,](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URLs here for us to interpret.

One more thing: If you've got both BIOS-mode and EFI-mode GRUBs, and if the BIOS-mode GRUB is the one that's failing, you can bypass it by going into your firmware and disabling the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), aka "legacy boot support" or words to that effect. I give this action perhaps a 1 in 3 chance of fixing your problem, but it's worth trying, especially if you remember following instructions to enable your CSM. Even if this action doesn't fix the problem by itself, it may facilitate the solution, once the cause is better understood.