# Fresh Install Boots Grub First

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I recently installed Ubuntu onto my laptop. It's the only operating system currently installed as far as I know. When I power on my computer, the Lenovo logo shows and then a GNU Grub 2.04 prompt is shown with instructions on getting help by pressing TAB; instead of showing me a password prompt to decrypt my hard drive. You can see that Grub prompt here:

[image: https://imgur.com/4B9EduZ]

I simply type 'exit' and I'm presented with my boot selection screen. From there I select the last option (which I've figured out is my new installation) and it boots Ubuntu normally. You can see the boot selection screen here:

[image: https://imgur.com/qFXwkpQ]

My question, of course, is: Why is this happening and how do I stop it and boot directly into Ubuntu?

I have an inkling this is an issue with Legacy and UEFI mode in my BIOS because on some previous installs, a while ago, I can remember messing with them. Also, reading through other questions, I've found them to be the most common issue with new installs booting Grub; as well, those threads are typically the most relevant to my situation. Here is my boot options screen in case it sheds any bright light:

[image: https://imgur.com/GCJ18eD]

There are many posts about similar issues but the one I found most helpful ([Fresh install boots into grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683981/fresh-install-boots-into-grub)) ends rather abruptly without actually solving my issue, but at least getting me a step ahead. It taught me of the bootinfoscript which I have run and hoping it would help you help me, I'll post the RESULTS.txt here:

https://pastebin.com/42wHpdUs

I really hope this was all clear enough that I might be able to get some help. I'm a big ol' newb on Linux so keep that in mind please. Thank you!

Comment: Next time you log in to your ubuntu desktop, open a terminal and try running `update-grub` (which is usually aliased to `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`) as root. Restart and see if the problem persists

Comment: @smac89 I ran the command `sudo update-grub`. No fix. Here is the output of the `update-grub` command:  `Sourcing file '/etc/default/grub'  
Sourcing file '/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'  
Generating grub configuration file ...   
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-45-generic  
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic  
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic  
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic  
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf  
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin  
done`

Comment: Did you disable secure boot in UEFI? You might have to modify some settings in the Security menu, please enter the menu and post a shot. Your Boot Priority might also need adjustment.

Comment: @Raffles In response to your first question, yes if you refer to my first post I speak of having changed some BIOS settings a long time ago. I can guarantee it was that one but I just as well remember enabling it again afterwards if that means something. Here is the security menu in my BIOS, the second image shows a menu one down from the security menu: https://imgur.com/a/26ZWf4j

Comment: UEFI and Legacy mode is a common problem, also if applicable to your laptop please make sure the SATA controller is in the AHCI mode (i.e not in the legacy or RAID or something). Other problems could be that the BIOS needs to be updated, and you could also try boot into a live session and carry out a [boot- repair](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/).

Comment: @Raffles I couldn't figure out how to check for AHCI mode in my BIOS; my BIOS is up to date; I ran boot-repair and it recommended I give you my boot info, like I did in the OP already. I gave it a read, from what I could understand the live session isn't in EFI mode. Hopefully that's helpful. Here's the new boot info: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MdsnRtTy3T/

Comment: Can you set an administrator password in BIOS and see if any new menus come up? If not, disable the password, then investigate the following:  from your pastebin info, maybe the disk has corrupt sectors and you might need to reformat the disk and reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was in fact related to UEFI/BIOS. In my attempt to make sure Ubuntu was installed UEFI, I actually ended up installing it in Legacy like a dummy.

I can *almost* guarantee my issue was an old Grub that was still installed. My BIOS settings make it so UEFI is always booted first, which is why my old Ubuntu's Grub would keep appearing when I powered my computer on. The reason boot-repair didn't work was cause I was trying to use it in a incorrectly installed Ubuntu (not UEFI), when the tutorial @Raffles gave me was for UEFI installs only. I of course didn't realize this until afterwards.

**All I did to fix: disable "Legacy Support" in my BIOS and then simply reinstall. It installed Ubuntu with UEFI so now I boot directly into it! Thank you to everyone that helped!**